# Active X Control C#

Tags: c#, activex

How to create an active x control so that it should read a input from the file and write a output to the file.

Answer (score 1):

**please note your activex controls are limited to IE**

using vb
http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~saul/vb_examples/tutorial10/activex01.html

using .net
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24089/Create-ActiveX-in-NET-Step-by-Step

Comment: I want it to be developed in visual studio c#